# Copy the value to rows for distinct values - Spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe. I want to copy the value of rows based on the specific column

```
ColumnA  columnB columnC
a         Null      Null
a          1          1
b          2          2
c          Null      Null
c          3          3
```

So in this dataframe ColumnC is a copy of ColumnB but , I want a single value for each value in ColumnA. If a value of Column A has null and a proper value, I want proper value in all places else Null.

Required dataframe:

```
ColumnA  columnB columnC
a         Null        1
a          1          1
b          2          2
c          Null       3 
c          3          3
```

I tried doing partitionby(ColumnA) but seems not working.

Can I get a scala code for this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to choose a B value for every A value.
This is a groupBy clause.
In order to correctly choose the value you need to find the proper aggregation function. In this case, the [first](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#first(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,ignoreNulls:Boolean):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function can be used:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}

df
  .groupBy($"columnA")
  .agg(F.first($"columnB", true) as "columnC")
```

This will give you a single value from B for every value A

```
columnA  columnC
a        1
b        2
c        3
```

You can then proceed to join it with the original DF by `A`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this would help me. But .agg(df.first($"columnB", true) as "columnC") is giving me error as too many arguments

Comment: @Chinti I think because you're calling `df.first(...`, while it's `F.first(...` in the answer, which I think F is an alias for `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`.

Comment: @AminMal true, I edited the answer to include that import